# Импорт данных из excel в структуру drupal7

Tags: drupal

Не получается реализовать импорт из excel файла с данными, в структуру друпала.
 Ищу в интернете подходящую документацию, но пока безуспешно. Для импорта использую модуль Feeds, основная проблема - это словари в данном типе материалов.
Как загружаются данные со словарями?

У меня есть тип материала - компания, часть полей например такие как (должность, тип предприятия, тип производства и т.д. в виде справочника) И множество остальных значений телефон, продукция и т.д.
Именно в данную структуру я и хочу выгрузить данные, но есть ещё момент, файл(.xlsx) очень большой ~170 тыс. строк.

Любые примеры, ссылки были бы полезны.

Comment: На сколько я помню, Excel может выгрузить свои таблицы в формате CSV. Ну а дальше смотрите в интернете туториалы (гугль их полно выдает) по импорту данных из CSV в Drupal.

Comment: Именно CSV я использую, а вот примеров подходящих не нашёл.

Comment: Например, видео http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kPwTyMPd7c 1 часть и дальше.

Comment: По видео я реализовал, но словари таксономии так и не импортировались. Или словари предварительно необходимо наполнить?

Comment: Да, с наполненными словарями работает, это конечно не совсем удобно, но спасибо. Это то, что было нужно